# WiX: Disable the Next Button Until Edit Control Contains a Valid GUID

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

Using WiX, what's the simplest way to disable the Next button on a page until the user has entered a well-formed GUID in an Edit (textbox) control?

I expect the answer to be Condition elements within the Next button control, but I can't figure out what the conditions would be. Do conditions support regular expression matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it, but you might be able to have a custom action that runs a script (e.g. .vbs file, an example of a CustomAction that runs a script can be found [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/02/14/from-msi-to-wix-part-6-customizing-installation-using-custom-tables.aspx)) which would take that value and check if it's valid. VBScript supports regular expression (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx)). That script would then set some property to true or false depending on if the guid is valid. This property would then be used in the condition.

Comment: Just a general warning about script custom actions: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmen/archive/2004/05/20/136530.aspx

Comment: @Yan Thanks for that! Good to know how Rob feels about this. To paraphrase: Using scripts in CustomActions can be opening a can of worms.